# Passing double values into 2D Array

Tags: java, arrays, double, 2d

I'm trying to initialize my 2D array in java by passing specific double values into it, but I'm returning an error " ']' expected".

```
double[][] EnglishToFrenchProb = new double[2][3];
    double[0][0] = 0.0; //unused
    double[0][1] = 0.08;
    double[0][2] = 0.06;

    double[1][0] = 0; //unused
    double[1][1] = 0.08;
    double[1][2] = 0.06;
```

What am I doing wrong, and I realise there's an easier way to pass values into 2D arrays but this is the only way I could think where I can index them easily by their own values (which I need to do)

Comment: ... what do you actually think you are doing in this?

Answer (score 3):

To set some value you have use variable's name:

```
EnglishToFrenchProb[0][0] = 0.00;
```

You can use also following syntax:

```
double[][] EnglishToFrenchProb = {{0.00, 0.08, 0.06}, {0.00, 0.08, 0.06}};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer to variable name:

```
double[][] EnglishToFrenchProb = new double[2][3];
EnglishToFrenchProb[0][0] = 0.0; //and so forth
```

Comment: @user1840051 nevermind. Check out handy array initialization expression in hsz's answer. Also if you find answer helpful, consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/151960). Please, read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)